Straight-line lift of simple loop on torus descends to a simple loop
In Farb and Margalit's primer on mapping class groups, they state on page 27 that if a closed curve in $T^2$ is simple, then its straight-line representative is simple.
That is, if you have a simple loop $\alpha$ in the torus and lift it to its unique path
in $\mathbb{R}^2$ starting at $(0,0)$ which ends at, say, $(p,q)$, then they claim that the
loop you get by composing the path $t \mapsto (tp,tq)$ for $t \in I$ is simple.
I don't see how to show this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Here is what I've tried so far: For simple cases, I'm not sure how to create a strong argument. The only intuition that I have for a case such as $(2,0)$ for example, would be that I can draw it with a single self-intersection, so to remove it, one would presumably have to pull in on of the bounding curves for some neighboring region which doesn't seem possible - but this is very informal, and what if the situation looks more complicated?
Maybe some sort of self-bigon criterion could be formulated?

What did you try to prove this? Did you try to work out any examples where the straight-line representative is not simple, e.g. the case $(p,q)=(p,0)$, $p>1$?

My apologies for not including what I've tried. I have now edited the question to include that.
However, even in the simple cases such as $(p,0), p>1$ as you mention, I cannot find a tool to apply to argue that the self-intersection could not possibly be removed.

Hint: The preimage of a simple loop in the universal cover will be an infinite collection of pairwise disjoint biinfinite topological lines invariant under the group of covering transformations.

@MoisheKohan: if the simple loop is contractible, won't its pre-image in the universal cover be an infinite disjoint union of simple loops?

@RobArthan: of course, I had in mind the specific examples I gave (which are actually the only examples one has to consider). In the book they assume that loops are homotopically nontrivial.

@MoisheKohan: I see. Thanks for the explanation.

@MoisheKohan I see. So I suppose the idea is then that we homotopy all the lines at the same time to a parellel collection of biinfinite straight lines? Then I would imagine that if these descended to a loop with self-intersections, we would necessarily have non-parallel lifts too, giving us the desired result since the lines are disjoint?

If $(p,q)\neq (0,0)$ the straight-line self intersects iff $(sp,sq)=(tp,tq)$ with $0\leq s<t\leq 1$, which happens iff $(t-s)(p,q)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$, which happens whenever $p,q$ not coprime - or in other words $(p,q)$ is a proper multiple of an integer vector, which is equivalent to the loop not being primitive in the fundamental group. So if a loop is non-trivial in the fundamental group and not primitive, then the straight line curve will be simple.  On the other hand if it is not primitive, then loop will not be simple in the first place (prop 1.5).  Either way you are done.

@tkf Yes, this is the part that is given. The part that wasn't clear was how to go from $\alpha$ being simple to the straight line representative necessarily being simple. When we have this step, we can apply the thing you wrote to conclude that $\alpha$ must be represented by a primitive tuple $(p,q)$.

I see - chicken and egg.
